# What are the weaknesses in Dragon City?

Tags: dragon-city

I want to know the weaknesses in Dragon city. What's good against what? Like what's good against a Legendary type Dragon? as an example.

Comment: Here is a helpful link: http://www.dragoncityegg.net/dragon-city-weakness-chart-guide/

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to list out... You can check out each element's weaknesses in battle here: http://www.dragoncityegg.net/dragon-city-weakness-chart-guide/

Of course, here is the full text if anyone needs it (Earth is Terra):

- An Earth-type dragon will face double damage from War and Metal, Half from Earth and Fire, and None from Lightning
- A Fire-type dragon will face double damage from Water and Lightning, Half from Fire and Metal, and None from Light
- A Water-type dragon will face double damage from Fire and War, Half from Water and Nature, and None from Earth
- A Nature-type dragon will face double damage from Earth and Ice, Half from Nature and Light, and None from Water
- A Lightning-type dragon will face double damage from Water and Light, Half from Lightning and War, and None from Meta
- An Ice-type dragon will face double damage from Fire and Metal, Half from Ice and Dark, and None from War
- A Metal-type dragon will face double damage from Lightning and Dark, Half from Metal and Earth, and None from Fire
- A Dark-type dragon will face double damage against Earth, Nature, and Light, Half from Dark and Lightning, and None from Ice
- A Light-type dragon will face double damage against Nature and Dark, Half from Light and Ice, and None from nothing (No attack can be negated by a Light-type dragon)
- A War-type dragon will face double damage against Water and Ice, Half from War, and None from nothing (No attack can be negated by a War-type dragon)
- An Pure-type dragon will take normal damage from every move except for a Ancient-type move, where it will deal half-damage
- A Legendary-type dragon will take normal damage from every move except for Physical attacks (half damage) and Legendary attacks (Double damage)
- Ancient dragons will always take normal damage (maybe half from Ancient attacks)

Note: All types except Legendary (and maybe Pure) will take half-damage if the attack type is equal to the defending dragon's type.